# How can I test snow melt system sensors?

Tags: boiler

I bought a place last summer with a hydronic snow melt system. If works when I turn it on manually.

How might I test that the sensors are operable in "auto" mode without waiting for a snowstorm?

Comment: I'm curious because i live in Texas and have never seen this... What does the sensor do?  Does it sense temperature or somehow see that there is snow cover with a light sensor?

Comment: If the sensor just depends on temperature, then some freeze mist (used to cool electronics when troubleshooting) may work.  Just spray it on the sensor.

Comment: Will need to know the type of sensor.  I doubt if it is just temperature since in some places it would be on for months.

Comment: Part of the challenge is that I don't know what type of sensors there are

Comment: I would take a look at the visible bits - pumps, plumbing, controller, whatever you can see and look for manufacturer name and model numbers. Contact the mfgr and ask them what kind of sensors work with this equipment and how to identify them. Ask them for a full installation/operating manual. They've got to have some sort of test procedure, and since we don't know any of these details, it's hard for us to look them up for you.

Comment: Many of the hydronic bits are (typically) going to be non-specific to snow-melting.

Comment: Try a couple buckets of ice spread out where the sensors are installed. Hit “auto” and stand back to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If it operates whenever it's cold, then I suppose you could see if it operates when it's "just cold"

Of course, that also wastes money on heating things when there's no snow, but given that these systems are vastly expensive to operate for what they do, that may not matter to you (and is bogglingly common for the few I've seen, which appear to be entirely based on fear of being sued for a slip on ice or snow justifying the sky-high operational cost of keeping a hunk of uninsulated concrete at 50°F/10°C all winter.)

If it's cold enough to be making frost in the mornings, turn it on and see if there's no frost on the heated surface (and often several inches beyond) in the morning.

With no idea where or what sensors are (supposed to be) operating it, any test other than that is difficult to manage.